# In Python how to reset the incrementor to the previous run in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

My question is:
In Python how to reset the incrementor to the previous last value in for loop?
I tried i=i-1 to reset the incrementor i to the last value but the for loop continues to increment the value without considering my statement i=i-1

Code is given below.

[my code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JltXn.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.  That said, you are using a ```for``` loop.  Changing the ```i``` value is pointless that way.  If you need to change/decrement the ```i```... use a ```while``` loop and then manually increment the ```i``` by default and decrement it under the specific conditions.

Comment: Please post code in a code block and not an image

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried to put the code as text in my question but it gives me this error. Im new to this so trying to figure out.       'Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.'